# where to use GPSStatus.getMaxSatelites()?

Tags: android, gps

`getMaxSatelites()`method in `GPSStatus`class always returns `constant 255`.

i am still confused where to utilize it? As no where the value can be changed.

Why android has provided us with this method.... still confusing!

Answer (score 0):

The `getMaxSatelites()` is a method that does not gives you the number of connected satelites but the maximum number that could be connected to your device. This is often 255.

See documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/GpsStatus.html#getMaxSatellites%28%29)

Comment: ok.but when i am counting availble satelites using getSatelites() method..sometimes i am getting more than 5000 satelites.max how many satelites can be connected to the device?.

Comment: This is really strange as you see the code source at this page: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/location/java/android/location/GpsStatus.java The method returns a static final int set at 255. With the doc that says:  * Returns the maximum number of satellites that can be in the satellite list that can be returned by getSatellites() *

Comment: Issue is Fixed.The issue was in counting availble satelites .getSatelites() method returning proper value